# the input tag is not working (redux-form)

Tags: reactjs, redux

the input boxes of redux-form are not showing on screen(not rendering) although I followed all instructions to install redux-form

here's the component where I am using the input tags:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class StreamCreate extends React.Component {
  renderInput({ input }) {
    return <input {...input} />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <Field name="title" component={this.renderInput} />
        <Field name="description" component={this.renderInput} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'streamCreate'
})(StreamCreate);
```

and I added the formReducer to the combineReducers():

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
import authReducer from './authReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  form: formReducer
});
```

Comment: it seems you didn't provide `type` attribute to your input. Can you try with `<input {...input} type="text"/>` ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé I added it now, it didn't make difference

Comment: do you have an error in the console ?

Comment: no, no errors at all

Comment: is your component `StreamCreate` rendered somewhere ? can you add a console.log in the `render` just to check the component is actually rendered ?

Comment: the component doesn't render, the console.log didn't work